# Intellij recognize Google Drive code

Tags: java, intellij-idea, google-drive-api

I'm trying to setup a project from the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java), to be capable of detect in Intellij the fucntions or objects used by this API.

For example:

`GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
 GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));`

**GoogleClientSecrets** is not recognizes.

I already perform [this](https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/quickstart-IDEA), but no solution.

Any idea how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Drive API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v3).

Add all the jars to the [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

`GoogleClientSecrets` is here:

```
google-api-services-drive-v3-rev61-java-1.22.0.zip\drive\libs\google-api-client-1.22.0.jar\com\google\api\client\googleapis\auth\oauth2\GoogleClientSecrets.class
```

Comment: That could solve the problem, but I just add and remove again the library from intellij and it works for me...